Set Pydantic BaseModel field type dynamically when instantiating an instance?
With Pydantic is it possible to build a model where the type of one of its fields is set via an argument when creating an instance?
For example:
class Animal(BaseModel):
    name: str

class Dog(Animal):
    # more custom fields...

class Cat(Animal):
    # more custom fields...

class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    pet: Cat | Dog
 
person_args = {
    "name": "Dan",
    # set which type to use via some kind of argument?
    "_pet_type": Dog,
    "pet": { 
        "name": "Fido",
        # ...
    },
} 
    
person = Person(**person_args)

I'm aware that typically you could use a discriminated union to resolve which type to use. However in this particular case the information for which type I should validate against exists outside of this set of data in another, related model.
Alternately could I use some kind of private field on the types being discriminated that I set but isn't included in validated output? Something like:
person_args = {
    "name": "Dan",
    "pet": { 
        "_pet_type": Dog, # exclude from output
        "name": "Fido",
        # ...
    },
} 
    
person = Person(**person_args)

I'd like to avoid use of a custom validator as I'm using FastAPI and I want the potential types to be reflected properly in the OpenAPI schema.
I'm currently on Pydantic v1.x, but would consider upgrading to v2 if it would help me solve this issue.

I would say your question is a little bit too vague to be answered successfully. Could you elaborate on "in this particular case the information for which type I should validate against exists outside of this set of data in another, related model"?

@M.O. Sure - to extend the example above imagine there is a Resident model that includes whether people are allowed to have a pet and if so which type. The Person model above relates to it. The knowledge of which type to use validating the pet exists in the Resident data, not in the Person or pet data.

Consider doing something like this:
class PetType(str, Enum):
    DOG = "dog"
    CAT = "cat"


class Animal(BaseModel):
    name: str

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, animal: dict) -> "Animal":
        """Build animal based on dict provided."""

        type_ = PetType(animal["type"])
        pet_mapper: dict[PetType, Type[Animal]] = {
            PetType.DOG: Dog,
            PetType.CAT: Cat,
        }

        return pet_mapper[type_].model_validate(obj=animal)


class Dog(Animal):
    pass


class Cat(Animal):
    pass


class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    pet: Cat | Dog

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, person: dict) -> "Person":
        """Build person based on dict provided."""

        return cls(
            name=person["name"],
            pet=Animal.from_dict(animal=person["pet"])
        )


person_args = {
    "name": "Dan",
    "pet": {
        "type": "cat",
        "name": "Fido",
    },
}

person = Person.from_dict(person=person_args)


Thanks! I was wondering if pydantic has a way to do this without me overwriting the processing, but this definitely looks like a path that could work.

I see, I haven’t found the out of the box solution yet although I’ve come across this problem many times. Anyway, I’ll share if I find!

Nice.  If you need extra speed, consider building the dict ahead of time and setting it on the main class  Animal.pet_dict = ....  Or you might even be able to use __init_subclass__ to assign the values against PetType.
